# How do I identify this button using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

The button is the "View All Suggestions" Button.

So I need to write line like:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("something here").click()
```

And it doesn't have to be by css. This is just an example. Any method that words will do.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code.  Take a look at https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html.  It highlights some locator methods that should suit you (e.g. `find_element_by_id` or `find_element_by_class_name`).

Comment: Is there a reason you have to select the element by its css?  There are other ways to select an element, such as by html tag type, html id, visible text, and so on.

Comment: @JohnGordon there is no restriction on how to select the element. it could be css or other methods. If you know how using other methods, then please submit an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click on the first occurrence, use this:

`browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a//*[contains(text(),"View All Suggestions")]').click()`

To click on n-th occurrence, use this:

```
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//a//*[contains(text(),"View All Suggestions")]')
elements[3].click() # <-- Click on the 3rd occurrence if it exists.`
```

Comment: Didn't work. selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException

Comment: Can you paste the HTML code? That will help us greatly :)

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Isn't that is what I have in the picture?

Comment: I've added another picture

Comment: I've updated my solution. It will click on the **first** occurrence of "View All Suggestions". If you need to click on the other occurrences you will need to use `.find_elements_by_xpath()` to store all occurrences in a list and click on the one that you want.

Comment: the list elements if of length zero